# Tcp windows service not creating any log file

Tags: c#, windows-services, background-process, tcpclient

I have created a Windows service Which will open the port and log the data in text file.It is asynchronous data communication allow to connect multiple Clients.But my problem is it is not creating any log file as well it is not logging any data.kindly guide me where i am doing wrong???
here is my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace TcpService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            SetupServer();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Service1._serverSocket = null;
        }

        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> _ClientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static int port = 10000;
        private static IPAddress iparr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.12");
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Setting Up server");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(iparr, port));
            _serverSocket.Listen(100);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            _ClientSockets.Add(socket);
            //Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                SocketError errorCode;
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = socket.EndReceive(AR, out errorCode);
                if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    received = 0;
                }

                byte[] databuf = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, databuf, received);
                string text = BitConverter.ToString(databuf);
                string time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                string dataline = time + "____" + text;
                AddtoLogFile(dataline);
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private static void AddtoLogFile(string Message)
        {
            string LogPath = @"D:\\Logfile\\";
            string filename = "Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt";
            string filepath = LogPath + filename;
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath);
                writer.WriteLine(Message);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, when you debug this code, what happens? Because I'm assuming you've debugged it to find out why it doesn't create your logfile.

Comment: Sorry I missed that ...When I debug the above Code It is creating the file but not logging the data...

Comment: How about empty exception ? "catch (Exception ex) {...}" probably is something here...

Comment: Nothing ...When the client is disconnected...The exception will be catch and  Console  will show that Client Disconnected as I don't need the time of the client Disconnection time I haven't given any code on exception...

Comment: Because you also put "AddtoLogFile(dataline);" inside try block. It means if an error like AccessDenied in LogFile, that exception is also gone. You will never know, what is wrong with your log file.

Comment: Not related to your current problem, but you're doing more work than you [need to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx): "If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file."

Comment: Then How to trace the problem Any suggestions Plz???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with the below code Every thing is working fine

```
  private static void AddtoLogFile(string Message)
    {
        string LogPath = @"D:\Logfile\";
        string filename = "Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt";
        string filepath = LogPath + filename;
        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, false))
            {
               using(StreamWriter writer1 = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                   if(File.Exists(filepath))
                   {
                       writer.WriteLine(Message);
                   }
                }
                //StreamWriter writer1 = File.CreateText(filepath);
                //writer.WriteLine(Message);
            }
```

Thank you guys....

Comment: The else branch is quite confused. It does not work, either. `using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Message);
            }` is all you need. No `if` at all. Or, `File.AppendText(...)`.